# Double Induction of $x^n < (n^n)(2^x)$

Tags: inequality, induction

For all real numbers $x, x < 2^x$.

Use this fact to show that for any positive integer $n$ :

> $x^n < (n^n)(2^x)$, for all real numbers $x > 0$.

---

Let f(x,n) be x^n < (n^n)(2^x)
then I proved that **f(1,1)** = 1 < 2 is True

Assume that **f(x,1)** is true too, x < 2^x.
Prove that **f(x+1,1)** is true, 
x+1 < 2^(x+1).

x + 1 - 2*2^x < 2^x - 2^x - 2^x + 1

x + 1 - 2*2^x < 1 - 2^x (Since x > 0)

x + 1 - 2*2^x < 0

x+1 < 2^(x+1) **(Proven)**

Let **f(x,n)** be x^n < (n^n)(2^x). **Prove that f(x,n+1) is true, x^(n+1) < [(n+1)^(n+1)] 2^x**

That's the problem, no matter how hard i tried, **I can't prove that f(x,n+1) is true**...

Can anyone out there please help me with it asap. Thank you in advance! (:

Comment: You cannot use induction on the reals !

Comment: You have to consider $x$ fixed and use induction on $n$, exploiting in the proof the "known" fact that : $x < 2^x$ for all *real* $x$.

Comment: Thus, the *base* step will be : "Let $f(x,n) = x^n$; then $f(x,1) = x^1=x < 2^x = (1^1)2^x$.

Comment: @MauroALLEGRANZA Ohh! So Inuduction don't work for reals. Then I can't say that this is a double induction anymore right? Since I only need to do induction on n.

Comment: @MauroALLEGRANZA For the base step, can I just let f(x,n) be x^n<(n^n)(2^x) then  f(x,1) = x < 2^x (True, as given in the question) ?

Answer (score 1):

We are told that 
$$t\lt 2^t\tag{1}$$ for all $t$.  The inequality we want to establish is equivalent to $\frac{x^n}{n^n}\lt 2^x$. This is equivalent to $\left(\frac{x}{n}\right)^n \lt 2^x$, which is equivalent, for positive $x$, to $\frac{x}{n}\lt 2^{x/n}$. Now put $t=\frac{x}{n}$ in (1).

**Remark:** One could alternately write the same argument as follows. We are told to assume that the inequality $t\lt 2^t$ holds for all real $t$.  Let $t=x/n$, where $x$ is positive. Then
$$\frac{x}{n}\lt 2^{x/n}.$$
Since $x$ is positive, taking the $n$-th power of both sides we obtain
$$\frac{x^n}{n^n}\lt 2^x,$$
and therefore $x^n\lt n^n2^x$.

Comment: Where did the t < e^t come from? I can understand until this part x/n<2^(x/n) only.

Comment: @Darren: Sorry and thank you! It comes from a typo,  $t\lt 2^t$ was intended (and used later). I write $t\lt 2^t$ instead of the given $x\lt 2^x$ because I later want to use it with $t=x/n$, and I thought let $x=x/n$ might be confusing.  Fixed, it now says $t\lt 2^t$.

Comment: but then t is not equal to x, is it because you take t as a real number too so t < 2^t  =  x < 2^x ?   Then I can just let t = x/n and say that so t < 2^t (As given in the question) ??

Comment: To say $x\lt 2^x$ **for all** $x$ is the same thing as saying $t\lt 2^t$ **for all** $t$, which is the same as saying that for all $u$, we have $u\lt 2^u$

Comment: Thanks a lot! Are you able to solve the same problem using inuduction? I'm struck at (x^k)(x^1)<x(k^k)(2^x), when I'm trying to prove f(x, k+1) = x^(n+1) < [(n+1)^(n+1)] 2^x

Comment: You are welcome. The proof above does not directly use induction. But it uses implicitly the fact that if $0\lt a\lt b$ then $a^n\lt b^n$, which can be proved by induction.

Comment: Can you please show me how to do it? I have been struck on this for days..

Comment: I have written out a complete non-induction proof. Do you mean that you want detail in going from $x/n\lt 2^{x/n}$, which we are essentially given, to the $(x/n)^n\lt 2^x$? Or in going from $(x/n)^n$ to $x^n/n^n$?

Comment: I totally understood your non-induction proof. But then now I'm trying to solve it using induction. As I have been trying lots of different approach using induction yet failed, so I'm eager to solve it using induction. Can you help me with it?

Comment: Maybe, if I can avoid stepping on ground already mentioned in the other answer. Will not get to it immediately.   I still do not quite understand what you want. Proofs by induction of the standard algebra moves in the proof I gave? That can be done, butis very boring. Or an induction proof based based on a manipulation of $(x/(k+1))^{k+1}$? That can be done, but looks to me too close in spirit to the sketch in the other answer.

Comment: I tried to prove using 0<a<b then a^n<b^n, which lead me to prove x < n+1 using induction. But I'm not able to prove it this way too. 
Actually I just wanted to **prove x^(k+1) < [(k+1)^(k+1)] 2^x from (x^k)(x^1)<x(k^k)(2^x) continuing on**. Do you have ways to prove it?
The Induction proof based based on a manipulation of (x/(k+1))^(k+1) work well, but yeah it make doing induction for this pretty redundant.

Comment: If you want to prove the thing about $a$ and $b$, suppose $a^k\lt b^k$, Then $a^{k+1}\lt a^k b\lt b^kb=b^{k+1}$, induction step done.

Comment: I understand about this "suppose a^k<b^k, Then a^(k+1) < (a^k)b < (b^k)b = b^(k+1)". But I just **don't get how to apply the a and b understanding into proving x^(k+1) < [(k+1)^(k+1)] 2^x** from (x^k)(x^1)<x(k^k)(2^x). I can't just take a = x and b = (k+1) because if then a^k < b^k cannot even be proven for the base term where k = 1.

Comment: I was just using the $a^n\lt b^n$ stuff to include induction in my proof. That takes care of the step from $x/n\lt 2^{x/n}$ to $(x/n)^n\lt (2^{x/n})^n=2^x$. Do you want instead an entirely separate proof that does not use my method? It can be done, but is less natural.

Comment: I thought for your proof , it's already completed, it's not necessary to include any induction, cause it's good enough. Yes, I'm actually all the while asking for an entirely separate proof that start with or use induction.

Comment: Since the other answer has been deleted, I may do that. But not with enthusiasm!

Comment: I also just realised that the other answer has been deleted.
But I can't solve the question using the hint given in the other answer. Can you? I will really appreciate it..